# How to customize UITableViewCell for string length

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have to fit strings within a table. The strings are of different lengths. The cell of the table should be sized according to string length.

I am using `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` .
But I could not use it properly. Can any one please suggest a solution?

Comment: More information would be helpful. What exactly would you like to see and what are you seeing now that doesn't look right? The code that doesn't work would be helpful as well.

Comment: when i put the lengthy strings in table. only part of the string is visible. I want the full string to be displayed in the cell. Each string may be different  length. So, each cell should be of different height. That is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delegate method [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](http://tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) to change the table view row heights.